# Func return not working in Python version 3.6.4 in zsh, use VS code

Tags: python-3.x, return, func

`def great():
  name = input('enter name: ')
  great = 'hello ' + name
  return great

great()`

The output is nothing return

enter name: dsfsf

What a problem?

working in VS code, python 3.6.4
for python all extension install.
In IDLE all work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your function with a print function or assign a variable to the function

```
def great():
    name = input('enter name: ')
    great = 'hello  ' + name

    return great

print(great())

# assigning a variable to the function call
function_output = great() # this assigns the "hello name" string `to the function_output variable`
print(function_output)
```